# What is the best practice to stop a Function chain execution on Async execution?

Tags: java, java-8

I have this function here:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> func = (value) -> value + 5;
        func = func.andThen((value) -> {
            //Imagine that here some code executed and raised an exception, I'm throwing it 
            //manually just for the sake of this example.
            throw new RuntimeException("failed");
        });
        func = func.andThen((value) -> {
            System.out.println("Reached last function !");
            return value;
        });
        executeFunction(func);
```

Now, you can see that I am throwing a Runtime exception in the first andThen method. That is because I want to prevent the second andThen to be executed. Is that the best way to do it?

Also, I notice that if I execute this function inside a different thread (async) the exception is not printed in my console, and I want to know that the exception happened.

```
private static void executeFunction(Function<Integer, Integer> function) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> function.apply(100));
    }
```

In this case, if I want to make sure that the exception gets logged, but that the next function in the andThen chain doesn't get executed, should I log and throw? Isn't it an ati-pattern?

Comment: Why would you invoke `andThen` if you never want it to run? Please give more context.

Comment: I want it to run if there are no exceptions in the first andThen, I am throwing just as an example but where you see the throw in the first andThen, just imagine that some code executed there fails and an exception happens.

Comment: Why does your function return a value if it never gets used? You're not going to be able to fetch said value if you provide it to CompletableFuture. Using a Function just for the sake of `andThen` is not a good idea either. Why not just make a Runnable that runs all your sequential Runnables?

Comment: I want to be able to chain actions.

Comment: It returns the value because the next node/function in the chain needs it.

Comment: To get the exception from CompletableFuture, just invoke a get() on it. The main thread and wait for the future to finish, and throws an ExecutionException if your future completed exceptionally.

Comment: I do not intend to ever call get(), I'm looking for a more reactive approach here. And I can't use CompletableFuture for other restrictions.

Comment: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> function.apply(100)) .whenComplete( (value,throwable) -> { if(throwable != null) throwable.printStackTrace(); });` or `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { try { function.apply(100); } catch(Throwable throwable) { throwable.printStackTrace(); } });`

Comment: @Rogerthat  The example you have provided is calling a function implicitly, waiting for it to complete which isnt reactive. It's a shame you cant use CompletableFutures,  could achieve the same chaining with thenCompose, and maybe handled the exeption with an async callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating and throwing lots of exceptions can become quite expensive, which is why they're supposed to be limited to exceptional circumstances. Instead, you can use [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for control flow:

```
func = (value) -> Optional.of(value + 5);
func = func.andThen((optionalValue) -> {
    // Instead of throwing an exception, return an empty Optional
    System.out.println("Log the failure");
    return Optional.empty();
});
func = func.andThen((optionalValue) -> {
    optionalValue.map((value) -> { // This lambda will only execute if optionalValue is not empty
        System.out.println("Reached last function !");
        return value; // map wraps this in an Optional
    });
});
// Finally, unwrap the value. Optional provides a number of ways to do this, depending on how you want to handle failure/empty
func = func.andThen((optional) -> optional.orElse(...));
executeFunction(func);
```

Comment: I like the use of Optional, that is closer to what I actually want to achieve, I will leave the question open a bit longer to see if a better idea comes up, if not I'll accept this response.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper for functions/runnables, that logs and quits when your task fails. Like so:

```
class Runnables
{
    public static Runnable trying(Runnable... runnables)
    {
        return () ->
        {
            int successes = 0;
            try
            {
                for(Runnable runnable : runnables)
                {
                    runnable.run();
                    successes++;
                }
            }
            catch(Throwable t)
            {
                logger.error("Exception thrown from "+successes+"th runnable: ",t);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then:

```
private static void executeFunction(Runnable... runnables)
{
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Runnables.trying(runnables));
}
```

Comment: Give me a bit of time and I'll write a wrapper for Functions as well.

Comment: That is not what I want, this does not give me the ability to chain multiple Runnable, it is just one.

Comment: *facepalm* @Rogerthat You just provide the multiple runnables as an argument to `Runnables.trying(runnable1, runnable2, runnable3...)` and it makes them into one chained runnable that runs them all...

Comment: If you observe carefully, "chaining" Functions with `andThen` eventually only ends up with a single Function at the end, too. It's just, that single Function runs all the composed functions in order.

Comment: I understand that, and that is the behaviour I want, but I want to know how do I break the chain if I have to without loosing the error...

Comment: Well, do you want to throw the error? Or log the error? It's all up to you. Replace the text `logger.severe("Exception thrown from runnable number "+successes+": "+t.toString());` with whatever you want to do, and that's what will happen.

Comment: @Rogerthat The chain automatically breaks when an error is thrown, which takes you to the `catch` block and prevents any further Runnables from execution.

Comment: @Rogerthat My experiments tell me that the canonical way to stop Function chain execution is by throwing and propagating an Exception. This probably means that stopping Function chain execution is not intended/desired except in exceptional circumstances. The reason that it's non-trivial to stop chained Functions is that `andThen` creates a lambda that calls `apply` in a recursive manner. So, you need an exception to propagate the error up the call stack. If you expect frequent exceptions, you should use a convention of flags (such as `Optional.empty()` vs present state)  to mark errors instead

Answer (score 0):

You can get desired behavior by using [`CompletableFuture.thenApply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) method. For example:

```
public class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Integer, Integer> fn0 = v -> v + 5;

    Function<Integer, Integer> fn1 = v -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("failed");
    };

    Function<Integer, Integer> fn2 = v -> {
        System.out.println("Reached last function !");
        return v;
    };

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fn0.apply(100))
            .thenApply(fn1)
            .thenApply(fn2)
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                // next line prints the exception thrown by fn1, wrapped in java.util.concurrent.CompletionException
                System.out.println("Failed with error: " + throwable); 
                return 0; // default value, used when exception is thrown
            });
  }
}
```

Basically, `CompletableFuture` chain will be interrupted by exception "out of the box", so no additional handling is required.

Alternatively, if you want a bit more general approach:

```
public class Answer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    executeAsync(() -> stepOne(100))
            .thenApply(Answer::stepTwo)
            .thenApply(Answer::finalStep)
            .exceptionally(Answer::handleException);
  }

  private static CompletableFuture<Integer> executeAsync(Supplier<Integer> task) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task::get);
  }

  private static Integer stepOne(Integer value) {
    return value + 5;
  }

  private static Integer stepTwo(Integer value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("failed");
  }

  private static Integer finalStep(Integer value) {
    System.out.println("Reached last function !");
    return value;
  }

  private static Integer handleException(Throwable throwable) {
    // next line prints the exception thrown by any step before, wrapped in java.util.concurrent.CompletionException
    System.out.println("Failed with error: " + throwable);
    return 0; // default value
  }
```

Notes:

- Using `thenApply` you can chain as many function calls as you need
- In the last example methods inside same class can be replaced by methods from other classes (not necessarily static ones)